# Copying Object results to reference problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm trying to create a Copy of my existing Object by doing this.
Somehow I'm constantly creating a copy by reference and not as a new object.

```
    const fieldSchema = [
        {
            addressType: '',
            addressSuffix: '',
            addressStreet: '',
            addressPostalcode: '',
            addressLocation: '',
            addressCountry: 'Germany',
        },
    ];

    //State
    const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState(fieldSchema);


    const handleMenuItemCopy = (event, index) => {
        const fields = [...inputFields];
        console.log('Existing Item(s):', inputFields);
        const duplicatedField = fields.splice(index, 1);
        console.log('Copied Item:', duplicatedField);

        const newFields = [...inputFields, ...duplicatedField];
        console.log(newFields);
        setInputFields(newFields);
    };


return (
    <>
     {inputFields.map((inputField, index) => (
         ...
         <TextField
            id={`addressPostalcode-${index}`}
            name="addressPostalcode"
            variant="outlined"
            label="Postleitzahl"
            className={classes.input}
            onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event, index)}
            value={inputField.addressPostalcode}
         ></TextField>
         ...
     }

     <Button
       classes={{
         root: classes.buttonBase,
         startIcon: classes.buttonStartIcon,
       }}
       variant="outlined"
       onClick={(event) => handleMenuItemCopy(event, index)}
    >
      Duplicate Fields
    </Button>
  </>
)
```

#### Live Example

1. Input some Data inside any Input
2. Click Button on Top right
3. Select **Duplizieren** (Duplicate)
4. Edit one Field of the Copy
5. Changes Immediately take also action in the First Object Field Set.

[image: Edit Object Reference Problem]

Comment: `const duplicatedField = fields.splice(index, 1);` `splice` doesn't *copy* things.

Comment: Also `const fields = [...inputFields];` only does a shallow copy of the array. `fields` and `inputFields` still share the same objects as items in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the actual object. `splice` doesn't do that, it just removes it from the array (which I don't think you wanted to do).

This copies the object at `index` and adds the copy at the end:

```
const handleMenuItemCopy = (event, index) => {
    // Use the callback form
    setInputFields(fields => {
        // Copy the array; the objects within it are still shared
        fields = [...fields];
        // Copy the one that's at `index` and push at the end
        fields.push({...fields[index]});
        // Return the new array
        return fields;
    });
};
```

It's a shallow copy, which is usually all you need, but see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) if you need to do a deep copy instead.

Comment: Thanks I really like your approach, it's clean and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the content of the `duplicatedField` array that you can do by changing this line:

```
const duplicatedField = fields.splice(index, 1);
```

to:

```
const duplicatedField = fields
  .splice(index, 1)
  .map(item => ({ ...item }));
```